# refs working on iOS but undefined on Android - React Native

Tags: react-native, picker

So I have two components

```
    <TouchableInput
      onPress={() => this.interestedInPicker.togglePicker()}
    />
    <RNPickerSelect
      placeholder={{}}
      items={[
        {
          label: 'text',
          value: 'value`,
        },
        {
          label: 'text'
          value: 'value',
        },
        {
          label: 'text',
          value: 'value',
        },
      ]}
      onValueChange={restInput.onChange}
      style={styles.interestedInPicker}
      value={restInput.value}
      ref={ref => (this.interestedInPicker = ref)}
    />
```

`RNPickerSelect` has height of 0 so it is hidden.
When I press on the `TouchableInput` I want the function `togglePicker` to trigger. This works on iOS but logs undefined on Android. When I console.log `this.interestedInPicker` I can see the method I need but when I log the whole expression it is undefined. Any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened this as an issue for library [RNPickerSelect](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/22) about a month ago.

It is a known problem.  The issue is that they need a way to trigger the picker programatically.  You might be able to find a temporary solution [HERE](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7817)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed o fix this bug by placing the `TouchableInput` inside `RNPickerSelected` like `<RNPickerSelected><TouchableInput stuff /></RNPickerSelected>` hope it helps :)